# How to set scope parameters with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, isolate-scope

I thought I'd mastered isolated scopes with custom directives, then hit this problem, which I've been struggling with for 3 hours now:

Once the isolated scope is created for the directive I thought you could set any scope data (in this case `greeting`) within the `controller` or `link` function. But referencing `{{greeting}}` in the HTML doesn't work, even though `greeting` it is shown in the scope when inspected via the console?

I thought the new isolated scope would be assigned to the directive `myDir` and than anything defined on that scope would be accessible within the HTML contents of `<my-dir>`. Obviously, I have a gap in understanding.

Any ideas please?

Plunker: [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DgGUMeH9CK82sKIrxT6u)

HTML:

```
<my-dir>
    Greeting: {{greeting}}
</my-dir>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('myDir', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.greeting = 'Hello';
            //this.greeting = 'Hello';

        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

          //scope.greeting = 'Hello';

        }

    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `scope: {}` with

```
scope: false,
```

that's not possible the current dom belongs to parent so it will consider only parent scope directice's isolated scope will not work.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I wish to isolate the scope rather than inherit / share the parent scope, which in this case is root I believe.

Comment: ah, so because the DOM has already been rendered to scope for that part of the DOM cannot be changed, right. So perhaps I could use transcendent in the definition object to clone and reinsert the content but with the new content referencing the new scope?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment wasn't very well written and it won't let me edit for some reason. I meant to ask whether using transclude might be a solution?

Comment: transclude is not the right concept over here since transclude works inside the directive not outside.

Answer (score 1):

> Refer to the [docs here - Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):
> That example is what you might be after.

For you case too, you can simply use ng-transclude, move the Greeting {{greeting}} to a template which you define in my-dir directive definitions.

> Directive definition in JS

```
        app.directive('myDir', function() {

            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {},
                controller: function ($scope) {
                    $scope.greeting = 'Hello';
                },
                template: 'Greeting: {{greeting}}',
                link: function(scope, element, attrs){

                  //scope.greeting = 'Hello';

                }

            };
        })
```

> HTML

```
<my-dir></my-dir>
```

> you just don't have to touch the link function or do anything out of the box.
>
> Working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/08tFyy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this works. Anyone see any downsides?

So within the `link` function, pass the `transclude` parameter, then set the `scope` for the transcluded element, thus:

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.greeting = 'Hello';

        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){

            transclude(scope, function(clone) {
                element.append(clone);
            });

        },
        transclude: true
    };
})
```